# Relationship between <RuntimeFrameworkVersion> and runtimeconfig.json includedFrameworks version for self-contained dotnet 6 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have a build system where I run the following command for over 10 applications in parallel.
`dotnet publish <project_name> --configuration Release --framework net 6.0 --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained True /property:WarningLevel=0 --output path/to/output`

The csproj of these projects contains (I omitted some stuff like project and package references)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net6</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>6.0.14</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

So these are all self-contained apps that will need the `6.0.14` runtime.

What is happening occasionally is sometimes when I look at the published app's `<project name>.runtimeconfig.json`
I see

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.10"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false
    }
  }
}
```

So the framework version is `6.0.10`, but for most published outputs I checked the framework version is `6.0.14`. This is happening for dotnet builds that happen on the same machine during the same build job, so there is no chance that the build machine changed between dotnet builds, which as I stated are kicked off in parallel.

What is the relationship between `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>6.0.14</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` and

```
"includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.10"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.10"
      }
    ]
```

is the fact that sometimes the `includedFrameworks` version is `6.0.10` indicating the `6.0.14` runtime is not being used?

I've read a lot about this and I would expect these versions to be the same.

Comment: I tried your publish configuration and command but get right version. <RuntimeFrameworkVersion> should have dominate the output version. How about clear the published file and repubish at csproj level?